# Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation

Tags: android, cross-platform, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

i'm using Nativescript it was working will
but, when i deleted android studio and setup it again every time i run any project there is an error

> Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to
>   build for Android, install Android SDK 22 or later.

i install sdk api 22 but also the same error
i  try tns doctor but also the same error

Comment: i think that nativescript does not see android directory , how can i know what is directory nativescript see?

Comment: you need to check for ANDROID_HOME enviroment variable

Comment: yes i reed this before but i do not know what is the meaning of ANDROID_HOME

Comment: Content of it is path where android is saved on your disk

Comment: I Checked it in C:\Users\Mohammed.Hassan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk and i found some folders like ..tools platforms platform-tools etc...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from setting the **ANDROID_HOME** environment variable, it's a good idea to set the **tools** and **platform-tools** folders in the **PATH**.

If you are on Windows

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Taken from this [installation guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/).

Comment: Doesn't help, as the issues is no one knows what the <install location> is.  I searched my system for 'android-sdk-windows' and the folder doesn't exist.  Yet, I'm running Android Studio and used the SDK Manager to install Android versions 4.4 through 8.0.